# conditional statements in derby

Tags: database, derby

It looks like [derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/manuals/index.html#docs_10.5) doesn't support conditional statements [IF]. How do we write

```
if exists (select 1 from customers where name='somename') 
    update customers ...
else 
    insert into customers ...
```

in derby? Derby doesn't have 'replace into' of mysql either.

Note: I am using derby as unit-testing replacement for mysql [that is production will use mysql and unit-test will use derby].

Answer (score 2):

What about http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefcasenullif.html#rrefcasenullif?

```
   CASE
      WHEN 1 = 2 THEN 3
      WHEN 4 = 5 THEN 6
      ELSE 7
   END
```

So maybe you can try something like:

```
CASE
 WHEN  select 1 from customers where name='somename' = 1 THEN update...
ELSE  insert...
END
```

I have no idea if that would work but it seems like a start. Good luck!

**edit:** After trying a few of these things out...I don't know if this will really help you. It doesn't seem like you can fire switch between SELECT and INSERT; it has to be one or the other and the CASE goes inside. What you want to do may or may not be possible...

Comment: This will not work.

Poorly documented Derby DB does not mention that CASE clause can only be used as a part of another SQL clause e.g. SELECT.

For instance,

SELECT CASE COUNT(*) WHEN 1 THEN 10 ELSE 20 END
FROM <table>
WHERE <condition>

Answer (score 1):

I know this might be too late but in case anyone is still looking for it:

MERGE

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-3155

For Example:

`MERGE INTO customers USING SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 ON customers.name='somename'
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET name = 'someothername', ...
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT(id, name, ...) VALUES (DEFAULT, 'someothername', ...)`