# What is the Derby equivalent to CREATE OR REPLACE?

Tags: sql, database, replace, derby

Does anyone know the Derby equivalent for the following?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW myView AS SELECT ...
```

My internet searching hasn't found anything clear. Wondering if I may have to do something similar to what I had to do for MSSQL:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'myView')
    DROP VIEW [dbo].[myView];

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[myView] AS SELECT ...
```

In which case I assume I'll have to [head down this path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317265/conditional-statements-in-derby).

Comment: See here: http://old.nabble.com/Create-table-if-not-exists--td22130625.html

Comment: and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866154/how-to-create-table-if-it-doesnt-exist-using-derby-db

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't exists.

Just try to perform the `SELECT` and if it fails catch it with the exception code:

```java
   try {
      // Try to perform your query on the view.
   } catch( SQLException e ) {
      // Compare exception code. If equals to X0Y32 then create the view.
   }
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not in a situation where I can try/catch using Java code. I really need to be able to do this purely in SQL. Is it possible to do something similar in SQL?

Comment: Nop. That syntax isn't standard is a language extension and isn't supported by Apache Derby. I think you should try your second approach then, sorry.